# How to use jQuery-UI-Tabs without making the text on my page bigger?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery-UI-Tabs to organize data on my web page.  However, I've noticed that whenever I use jQuery-UI-Tabs on any page, it seems to make the text inside the tabbed elements bigger.

How can I make jQuery-UI-Tabs work without changing the size of the text on my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better override its size setting by creating custom UI Theme or just overloading its settings in your own css

Comment: Any idea what classes I should be over-riding?

Comment: OK, I've figured it out.  The class to override is `ui-widget`

Comment: great you already discovered it, but just in case http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and Inspector are your friends